# What is the best way to enable invalidate inputs?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We have an ASP.Net webforms page. On the page load event, the page fills some inputs with data. Then blocks them so a user cannot edit them. Unfortunately some data appears to be wrong, so the ASP.Net validators won't allow the user to post the form.

There was a decision to unblock the invalid inputs to allow users to edit them. We have a number of ASP.Net validators on the page, including custom validators. Can I use these validators to validate data in the OnLoad event and unblock the invalid fields or do I need to unblock them manually checking every field? What is the best way to achieve the result?

Comment: Why not just unblock them all? Users can unblock those "blocked" form fields themselves, so unless you fully trust your users and know they aren't doing this, then they can be changing data you don't expect them to change. It's also curious that you are populating fields with invalid data anyway.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Thanks for your suggestion! I see what you mean but I'm not in charge of taking this decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no code, I'm only guessing this should work with your logic. Basically, after you set the value for all of the fields, you can run `Page.Validate()` and set the visibilities based on the validity of the data.

```
// set all your values
_textBox1.Text = "Some Value 1";
_textBox2.Text = "Some Value 2";
Page.Validate();
_textBox1.Enabled = !_textBox1RangeVal.IsValid;
_textBox2.Enabled = !_textBox2RequiredFieldVal.IsValid;
```

Comment: I wish I could avoid boilerplate code. I'm getting a collection of controls which validators validate and set them Enabled property. Looks rather strange. I just wanted to make sure that there are no other options. Thank you!